# ZipArchive Permission denied

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-16.04, octobercms

I create my site with OctoberCMS in localhost, and it's really fine. But then I transfer to the Ubuntu server (Nginex) and want to download plug-in or update in server. I get this error:

> "ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied" on line 75 of /home/admin/web/mymovielist.eu/public_html/vendor/october/rain/src/Filesystem/Zip.php

Of course then i install Zip, but on the internet I found that maybe need to add extension to php.ini file. But don't sure where and what text should add...

Then I give permission root 777 this file, and other. Folder ant etc... But nothing working for now. Somebody, help me.

Answer (score 3):

Seems when you transfer file from localhost to server, you may be logged in to ubuntu as `root` user or other user (or if you used ftp you may be using other user)

`Nginex` uses `apache` as back-end so now when you perform any read write using `website` all operation is done under apache user(**default**) `www-data`

and when you `download plugin` or `update CMS`, website try to download new files in to temp director that is fine, now it try to extract that files into plugin so may be its not having write access to to that location and its your site `root-dir/plugins`.

so you can use this command to give `www-data` ownership of that folders so it can write there,

```
// sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/your-site-location-root
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/admin/web/mymovielist.eu/public_html
```

if you are using this command as root user you don't need to add `sudo`

> this command need to be fire under **root** user.

now it can able to write files there.

> if we follow your way then **Then I give permission root 777 this file**

you are correct but you need to give this permission to root directory as we need to write files inside it, as `/home/admin/web/mymovielist.eu/public_html/vendor/october/rain/src/Filesystem/Zip.php` this file just executes the commands so if you give it permission then its of no use,

you need to fire this command,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/admin/web/mymovielist.eu/public_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to install 7z with `sudo apt install p7zip-full` and uncompress the archive with `7z x archiveName.7z`